# Cohomology of quotient by free action

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, equivariant-cohomology

Let  $G$ be a finite group. Let $G$ act freely on a CW-complex $X$. I heard that the following fact is true.

**Claim.** The canonical map $H^*(X/G,F)\to H^*(X,F)^G$ is an isomorphism, where $F$ is a field so that $|G|$ is invertible.

**I am looking for a reference to  this fact.**

Comment: Hatcher, Proposition 3G.1. The proof is short and the essential content is the construction of a transfer map going the "wrong way", so that one of the composites is obviously multiplication by |G|.

Comment: In the characteristic zero case, see Proposition III.2.4 of Bredon's "Introduction to compact transformation groups"

Answer (score 15):

This is true even if the group does not act freely.  See Proposition 1.1 of my notes [here](https://www3.nd.edu/%7Eandyp/notes/FiniteOrderHomology.pdf).  I deal with simplicial complexes and work over the rationals, but the statement you give can be proved the same way.

Comment: Couldn't you simplify the argument by ignoring representation theory and just observing that if R is a common ring with $|G|$ invertible $e=1/|G|\sum_{g\in G}g$ is an idempotent with $eV=V^G$ for any RG-module V. Since multiplication by an idempotent is obviously an exact functor  taking invariants commutes with homology.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg Sorry, I don't understand, what do you mean? Certainly in general taking invariants is not an exact functor - if it would be, there would be no group cohomology.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: That idempotent does not exist if the order of G is not invertible.  Multiplying by an idempotent is definitely exact.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg: I think that is basically the same argument, but expressed in different language.  You are just projecting onto the isotypic component of the trivial representation.  I find it easier to understand when put in the context of representation theory, but someone like you who does a lot of ring theory might have other preferences.

Comment: Hm seems to be right. So the category of $\mathbb Z[\frac1{|G|}][G]$-modules is semisimple??

Comment: @AndyPutnam, yes and no. My point is other isotypic components are unnecessary and so you don't need ask modules projective.  If $|G|$ is invertible the R-cohomological dimension is 0 and so taking invariants is exact. So the homological argument you give only users fields to relate homology and cohomology.  But it's not a big difference.  I guess my quibble is that when doing monoid cohomology these kinds of arguments can work even though monoid algebras are never semisimple because the trivial module is often projective

Comment: A group ring RG cannot be semisimple unless R is semisimple because of the augmentation homomorphism.  It is just the trivial module that becomes projective when |G| inverts.

Comment: "Ask" should be "all"

Comment: I guess the point I am belaboring is that Maschke's theorem is really about the trivial module being projective if |G| is invertible in R. Suppose R is a ring with |G| invertible.  Then any RG-module that is R-projective is RG-projective.  This because $Hom_{RG}(M,-)\cong Hom_R(M,-)^G$ as functors where G acts on R linear maps by $(gf)(m)=gf(g^{-1}m)$. Since all modules over a field are semisimple this gives semisimplicity of group algebras in good characteristic